# Access from LAN and remotely to the same svn server

Tags: svn, server, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-15.10

I have my own "server" (old laptop) which I use for SVN, Samba and some other things.
I own another Laptop which I sometimes use from my home and sometimes outside. Right now, I can sync via SVN locally and it works great.
I was wondering if there's any way to be able to sync when I'm outside without loosing the possibility to sync when I'm home.

I actually sync via svn+ssh on a non standard port and I'd like to keep it that way.

After doing some research, it seems the best option I've found is setting up a VPN server in order to "get inside the LAN from outside", but I've been following plenty of tutorials and I couldn't make it work for my Ubuntu Server 15.

I've also found the svn-sync command, but as far as I've read it wont do what

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common answer: "It depends"

1. How does you connect to WAN (i.e you have one interface for all or at least WAN+LAN)
2. Do you have direct connection to WAN or NAT?

Anyway, you have to have SVN (ssh) to listen on interface, which can be reached from external world (IP of remote client doesn't play game in this case)

Comment: @lazy-adger I'm sorry, I think I didn't explain myself. Let's say I have the repo "foo" checked out (locally) in my personal laptop. I want to be able to send commits while I'm not inside my LAN

Comment: @Ckubrak - for LAN you have `LAN-URL` for your WC, outside LAN the same repo will|can be visible at `WAN-URL`. Relocate WC before commit to "current" URL and commit. Maybe, the same URL will be nicer (using local hosts-file)

Comment: Do you mean that when I'm home I should "svn checkout svn+ssh://192.168.1.10" and when I'm outside I should "svn checkout svn+ssh://externalip" before I start commiting files?

Comment: @Ckubrak No. you have to `svn switch <NEEDED URL>` in **existing WC** and commit